# Automapper: Mapping single object to list of objects using a converter and derived mappings

Tags: c#, inheritance, mapping, automapper

I have a requirement to map a single object to a list of objects. I'm doing this by way of an automapper type converter.

The objects being mapped are part of 2 inheritance hierarchies and my goal is to reduce the repeated number of mapping configurations that I currently need to explicitly specify.

The following is a condensed code example. I've simplified the list projection condition for brevity.

**The inheritance hierarchies:**

```
public class BaseA {
    public Guid Id1 { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class BaseB {
    public Guid Id2 { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class DerivedA : BaseA {
}

public class DerivedB : BaseB {
}
```

**The type converter:**

```
public class BaseAToBaseBConverter<TBaseA, TBaseB> : ITypeConverter<TBaseA, List<TBaseB>>
    where TBaseA : BaseA
    where TBaseB : BaseB
{
    public List<TBaseB> Convert(TBaseA source, List<TBaseB> destination, ResolutionContext context) {
        if (destination == null) {
            destination = new List<TBaseB>();
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < (int) context.Items["InstancesToCreate"]; i++) {
            destination.Add(context.Mapper.Map<TBaseA, TBaseB>(source));
        }

        return destination;
    }
}
```

**The mapping profile:**

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile {
    public MappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<BaseA, BaseB>()
            .ForMember(destination => destination.Id2, o => o.MapFrom(source => source.Id1))
            .IncludeAllDerived();
        CreateMap<BaseA, List<BaseB>>().ConvertUsing<BaseAToBaseBConverter<BaseA, BaseB>>();

        CreateMap<DerivedA, DerivedB>();
        CreateMap<DerivedA, List<DerivedB>>().ConvertUsing<BaseAToBaseBConverter<DerivedA, DerivedB>>();
    }
}
```

**The tests:**

```
private IMapper _mapper;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp() {
    _mapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc => {
        mc.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
    }).CreateMapper();
}

[Test]
public void Map_SingleBaseAToList_ReturnsList() {
    var baseA = new BaseA();
    var baseB = _mapper.Map<BaseA, List<BaseB>>(baseA, options => options.Items["InstancesToCreate"] = 2);

    Assert.Multiple(() =>
    {
        Assert.That(baseB.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(baseB.Select(x => x.Id2).Distinct().Single(), Is.EqualTo(baseA.Id1));
    });
}

[Test]
public void Map_SingleDerivedBaseAToList_ReturnsList() {
    var derivedA = new DerivedA();
    var derivedB = _mapper.Map<DerivedA, List<DerivedB>>(derivedA, options => options.Items["InstancesToCreate"] = 2);

    Assert.Multiple(() => {
        Assert.That(derivedB.Count, Is.EqualTo(2));
        Assert.That(derivedB.Select(x => x.Id2).Distinct().Single(), Is.EqualTo(derivedA.Id1));
    });
}
```

The above works fine. However in reality BaseA and BaseB are abstract classes with heaps of derived objects hanging off of them. This means I end up with a mapping profile that is quite long and highly repetitive. What I would like to know is if there is some way to specify a single `ConvertUsing` for the single to list on the base types and have the derived types use that definition, like we can for the type to type mapping. Something like the following:

```
CreateMap<BaseA, BaseB>()
    .ForMember(destination => destination.Id2, o => o.MapFrom(source => source.Id1))
    .IncludeAllDerived();
CreateMap<BaseA, List<BaseB>>()         
    .ConvertUsing<BaseAToBaseBConverter<BaseA, BaseB>>()
    .IncludeAllDerived();

CreateMap<DerivedA, DerivedB>();
CreateMap<DerivedA, List<DerivedB>>();
```

This isn't permitted as there is no direct conversion between a `List<BaseB>` and a `List<DerivedB>`. Is there another way to get the mappings to work like this?

Comment: Instead of the `List` derived maps, try [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/6354d80c51f31f3bdb36002b5f360ebdab55b4db/src/UnitTests/Mappers/CustomMapperTests.cs#L134).

Comment: Another option is a generic map from `object` to `List<>`.

Comment: I did try an open generic but it was too broad, the mapper was matching on things I didn't it to match (to further complicate it, I am using the same converter to a List<> to List<> as well). I'll try the custom mapper approach. I was able to get what is probably similar functionality with an inline ForAllMaps case but it didn't lend itself to being extensible

Comment: You do have to work with AM, not against it :) Customizing enumerable mapping is already a code smell. So tread with care.